# Gmap not displaying

Tags: 7, location, google-maps

I have [Gmap](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap) and [Location](https://www.drupal.org/project/Location) module. I have created a content type and also added a field **location** with term reference(Taxonomy term). I have just added a content and selected one location. But I can't see the *google map* in the content. I have created taxonomy term with location detail.

Answer (score 0):

you can view it go to **content-type>>manage display>>specific field** change display setting :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But iam still confused . My taxonomy term is eg: geneva. I need that location map, when i selected it in a content.

Comment: you enter your location in geofield then module will get your location